# Python requests acting weirdly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When trying to get html code from link (https://sourceforge.net/projects/easyminer/files/latest/download) I'm getting a lot of weird symbols.

However, it's not happening when trying with other websites.

Code:
[image]

Console:
[image]

Comment: When I click the link, it is an EXE file (executable) which means it is in binary format. You don't expect it to be text format.

Comment: When I open this link, the download should begin in 5 seconds. From there I need to find a refresh link. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a `User-Agent` as normal browser, sourceforge will return a html page, otherwise a 302 redirect to the binary download link.

```
>>> r = requests.get("https://sourceforge.net/projects/easyminer/files/latest/download", headers={"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
>>> r.text[:50]
'<!doctype html>\n<!-- Server: sfs-consume-5 -->\n<ht'
```